# Shortcut for New Folder for windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, directory, keyboard-shortcuts, tweak

Can any one tell me some tweak to create a New Folder by using keybords shortcut keys for Windows XP???
As it is ctrl + shift + n in Windos 7.

Comment: That's not a programming question. Try SuperUser.com for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this shortcut key combination : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions here. It encourages more off-topic questions. If you're not sure what's OK to ask here and what isn't, see the [help] to become more familiar. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ken,
I'll take that in mind in the future.